# Android Intent.ACTION_CALL: phone number with # char

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to make a phone call to `*142#`

However, it dials `*142` only, the `#` is ignored.

Here is my code

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.balance);

myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + telephoneNumber));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

I set the telephoneNumber as `*142#` , but still it dials `*142`. What can I do to make sure it dials `*142#` ? with the `#` at the end ?

Answer (score 1):

URL encode the number with `URLEncoder`.

`#` has special meaning in URI syntax and needs to be encoded as `%23` to be treated literally as `#`.